# E-Reader with decent browser for rendering openHAB dashboard

Tags: kindle, ebook-readers, e-ink

I'm running openHAB on my Raspberry Pi 4 with several dashboards. Now I want to display one of these dashboards on an E-Ink display and I'm looking for a good device. The openHAB dashboard is just a website (HTML with a bit of JavaScript - VueJS), therefore all I need would be a decent web browser to render the website onto the E-Ink display. The website's JavaScript part keeps track if some values change in the background and only refreshes the necessary dashboard elements - so it's really important that the browser supports JavaScript and not only renders HTML.

Now I'm thinking about buying a cheap second-hand E-Reader to display the openHAB dashboard. For this, I've tested the built-in browser of a PocketBook Touch HD and a Kindle Touch (7th Gen., KT2). It works with the PocketBook but not with the Kindle.

Since I don't want to spend the money for a second PocketBook, I'm looking for an older Kindle which probably has a more modern browser to render the openHAB dashboard.

It would be great if you guys could recommend me a couple of devices that should be modern enough to properly support the openHAB website.

Thank you!